# merging two Jsons in powershell

Tags: json, windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have the following two Objects , which have been got from 2 Json file using:

```
$Env = ConvertFrom-Json "$(get-content "C:\chef\environments.json")"
$Roles = ConvertFrom-Json "$(get-content "C:\chef\roles.json")"
```

Heres the out put after conversion :

```
PS C:\chef> $Env

run_list
--------
{recipe[djin_chef-max_any::default]}


PS C:\chef> $Roles


7-zip             : @{home=%SYSTEMDRIVE%\7-zip}
cookbook_versions :
default           : @{env=development}
modmon            : @{env=dev}
paypal            : @{artifact=%5BINTEGRATION%5D}
seven_zip         : @{url=https://djcm-zip-local/djcm/chef}
task_sched        : @{credentials=XN$q}
windows           : @{password=K1N5}
```

I need to merge these two Json objects in powershell and I tried the following:

```
PS C:\chef> $Roles+$Env
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $Roles+$Env
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Is there another elegant way of doing it if I am doing it wrong or why am I getting this error ?

Comment: Asking to `merge two JSONs` makes no more sense than asking to `merge a photo and a video`. It's entirely possible - once you decide whether you want the picture at the start, at the end, as an overlay in a specific place, inserted every other frame, as a transparent watermark in some corner, in a bigger frame next to the video image... JSON  isn't a data structure, it's a serialisation format for many data structures. They won't necessarily mash together - you need to unpick what the datastructures are and how exactly you need them to merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$Env` only has one property, so you could add a new member to `$Roles`:

```
$Roles | Add-Member -NotepropertyName run_list -NotePropertyValue $Env.run_list
```

This syntax work in PowerShell v3, but you listed v2 and v2 in your tags.. so for v2:

```
$Roles | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name run_list -Value $Env.run_list
```

Comment: what if Env had more than one property ? Any to add and merge them together ?

Comment: @Scooby you could iterate over `$Env.PSObject.Properties` and programatically add each member.

Comment: could you provide an example for that  with made up values ??